# Which sentence is correct of these two?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. What if my plans for the future **won't** work out because the virus never stops?
2. What if my plans for the future **don't** work out because the virus never stops/will last forever?

Comment: They mean slightly different things...please provide context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What if my plans for the future won't work out" means that he has plans which he is going to execute in the future, but they won't work out in the future.
"What if my plans for the future don't work out" means that he has plans which he is going to implement now, but they are going to have an effect on his future.

So which one is right depends on the context. Just use the one which fits in best. But if you're just answering a grammar question without context, then the one with 'don't' seems better.